# apply condition to n largest in a lambda function after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I need to find the largest value of a column dataframe ('BlockNumber') for each of my subjects and get all the correspondent rows of the dataframe. The code below works. However, I also want to get additionally all the dataframe rows correspondent to the previous 5 BlockNumbers of my nlargest, i.e: nlargest-5 < BlockNumber <= nlargest. For example, if a subject has a BlockNumber that goes until 100, I want to get all rows from BlockNumber 95 to 100. How do I define this in my lambda function?

`max = df.groupby('subject').['BlockNumber'].apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(keep='all'))`

Comment: You already get this, as the default `n` for `nlargest` is `5`, so it's not clear what you want. So you'll need to supply an copyable example with desired output.

Comment: I want to be able to insert this condition: nlargest-5 < BlockNumber <= nlargest in my lambda function.  The desired output is a final dataframe with all rows from the last 5 BlockNumbers of each subject. Please note that each subject has different BlockNumbers completed, that is why I need to check the nlargest for each of them.